# Como uma aplicação NodeJS é distribuída para cliente?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Estou dando uma olhada em NodeJS e me surgiu uma dúvida sobre sua distribuição.

Supondo que tenho uma empresa, e utilizo Express/NodeJS para criar um serviço REST simples para minha aplicação principal.
Para instalar esse servidor em um cliente, eu precisaria instalar NodeJS nesse servidor?
Não existe um... servidor principal(coisa como Wildfly, Apache, Xamp, etc...) para suportar um servidor NodeJS?
E o cliente, poderia simplesmente editar os arquivos .js do node?

Comment: Sim você precisa instalar o nodejs no servidor assim como teria que fazer com aqualquer linguagem backend (js não é backend mas no node roda no backend), mas não entendi o problema, assim como o cliente pode alterar os arquivos .js ele poderia editar os arquivos .php  e etc

Comment: Ah sim, PHP também tem esse problema... só Java ACHO que tem as gerações do .war que impedem de editar, não é?

Comment: Se for como Amazon, você pode instalar o Node.js e depois os pacotes, se for pra contratar algo diferente então pode contratar uma servidor já com suporte a Node.js, como KingHost, Uol ... se eu não me engano [heroku.com](https://www.heroku.com) também suporta node.js, assim como suporta RubyOnRails e Python (não lembro, faz tempo que usei).

Comment: então você quer uma linguagem compilada e não interpretada, como o js

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Respondendo ao seu primeiro comentário: JS roda sim em server-side, com node.js, existem muitos sites assim, você pode criar um site do zero, controlando o http você mesmo pelo seus JavaScript, ou usar um framework que facilita como o "Express".

Comment: @RafaelMoreira a melhor solução para impedir do cliente editar os arquivos do meu ponto de vista seria você manter a hospedagem contigo e ele pagar ou pagar para você, pois mesmo que fosse Java ou aplicações encriptadas, existe a possibilidade de ocorrer a "engenharia reversa".

Comment: @RafaelMoreira Só pra constar mais um detalhe, se você tiver controle sobre as portas do teu servidor e puder instalar qualquer coisa, como Amazon EC2 por exemplo, você poderia instalar qualquer coisa e liberar a porta, ou até mesmo usar Fast-cgi com Node.js (assim o apache se comunicaria com o Node.js) e apontar para um subdominio só para o REST.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o que queria dizer que js não roda naturalmente no lado do servidor mas que pode rodar com usando o node

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam é bem mais comum do você imagina e é totalmente natural, assim como existem até executáveis escritos em C ou C++ que são compilados em executáveis e rodam viam Fast-CGI (ou até em CGI, que é uma "porta" bem obsoleta).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento então o js foi criado para ser usado no do lado servidor? Sempre achei que a ideia inicial era uma linguagem que seria interpretada pelo browser

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam existem inumeros motores JavaScript, inclusive antes do JavaScript ser popular, quando JS era algo opcional e geralmente tinhamos que ativar manualmente (meados de 1995 a 1998, nessa época internet nem era algo conhecido direito no Brasil), a Microsoft criou um JavaScript proprio (já que JavaScript foi criado para netscape, antigo Firefox) chamado JScript (sim o nome é similar), na época PHP nem era popular também e estava no começo ainda, quase tudo era feito em Perl e C e compilado para rodar via CGI (é uma "porta" que hoje é obsoleta), então alguns anos depois...

Comment: ... a microsoft criou o seu ambiente ASP para web (em 1996) e com ele era possivel criar aplicações com VBScript, JScript ou PerlScript, todos ports da linguagens existentes, ou seja de certa forma sim, JavaScript já podia ser rodado em servidores, quase que no mesmo tempo que começou a ficar popular no front-end. Linguagens propriamente web como PHP só vieram a se tornar mais populares alguns anos depois, ou seja web antes disso tudo era tudo via porta CGI que tecnicamente pode rodar qualquer coisa que escrita para se comunicar com ela e com o protocolo HTTP...

Comment: ... nos dias de hoje temos muitas soluções web e node.js é uma delas, é tão natural quanto PHP e quanto Java para web. Note que PHP foi criado em 1994, mas era algo mais de uso pessoal e foi só se tornar algo mesmo para uso em servidores na versão 2 e 3, que foi alguns anos depois... Se hoje os servidores tem PHP pronto para usar não quer dizer que é porque é natural, mas sim porque as hospedagens configuram eles para ser assim, assim como tem hospedagens configuradas para Python, Rails, Scala e diversas outras tecnologias. @GuilhermeCostamilam existe bastante história na evolução da web.

Comment: Valeu pela aula de história, não sabia desse JScript da microsoft

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam então JavaScript na verdade pertence a Mozilla, o que outros navegadores usam são seus proprios motores com linguagens idênticas e todas seguem o ECMA (https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). Nós chamamos de JavaScript por simplesmente o Netscape ter sido o primeiro a implementar, é como chamar toda esponja de aço de "bom bril", na verdade bom bril é marca, existem diferentes esponjas de aço, mas como é muito popular e antiga a marca, então acabamos por usar isso como nome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com Node.js (que lhe permite cria aplicações para **server-side**) e supondo que você tenha controle sobre os seguintes aspectos do teu servidor:

- Portas de entrada em saída
- SSH (ou possa instalar diretamente qualquer coisa no teu servidor)

Você poderia simplesmente liberar as portas para criar um servidor para sua API, ou então poderia usar algo como:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fastcgi

Com isto **creio eu** que você poderia se comunicar com o Apache ou Ngnix, então criaria um VirtualHost no Apache ou um host no nginx.conf para aportar para a porta do FastCGI que esta rodando sua aplicação escrita para Node.js

Ou acaso esteja usando Express (que é bem mais provável), você poderia simplesmente usar o `ProxyPass` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) com `VirtualHost` no Apache, assim:

```
<VirtualHost api.site.com:80>   
     ServerName api.site.com 
     ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:5000/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Dessa forma creio que é bem mais fácil que usar qualquer módulo para Node.js, pois bastaria usar o que já tem, claro que neste caso também depende de você ter controle sobre o servidor.

> PS: `http://localhost:5000/` seria o host local e porta para a aplicação em Express

---

> E o cliente, poderia simplesmente editar os arquivos .js do node?

O cliente só poderia editar os seus `.js` ou `.php` se ele tiver acesso ao servidor, se ele tem ele pode "estragar tudo", ou modificar, ou pedir para quem quer que seja modificar isto, mas se o seu intuito é proteger os códigos, então encriptação poderia ser uma possivel tentativa, no entanto nem mesmo códigos encriptados ou compilados estão "a salvos", existe engenharia reversa, ainda existe a possibilidade se o cliente comprou de você o código é dele e se ele exigir você vai ter que fornecer, não vou entrar neste assunto, pois isso vai para o lado juridico, do qual não tenho conhecimento para falar.

Voltando ao que importa, como eu disse, nada esta livre de fato, engenharia reversa é complicada mas não é impossível, então se o seu objetivo é impedir que quebrem a aplicação a solução que lhe proponho é simplesmente você ser o único que controla o servidor, com `ProxyPass` por exemplo você pode contratar uma hospedagem a parte e o servidor do seu cliente apontar para o endereço deste outro servidor.

```
<VirtualHost api.sitedocliente.com:80>   
     ServerName api.sitedocliente.com 
     ProxyPass "/" "http://hospedagemapartequecontratei.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Claro que isso vai para o lado da "segurança", se o objetivo é que o cliente só acesse via `api.sitedocliente.com` e deseja impedir o acesso ao `hospedagemapartequecontratei.com` então uma solução simples e minima seria checar o IP do servidor que requisitou o outro, ficaria assim:

- No seu servidor com Node.js você deve checar o valor de `request.connection.remoteAddress`, supondo que o teu cliente tenha um IP fixo no servidor, desta forma poderia limitar o acesso somente a este IP.
- Se não tiver um IP fixo, ou isto for inviável pode então tentar limitar o acesso com [`x-headers`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers), que são configurados automaticamente pelo ProxyPass, então checaria se `X-Forwarded-Host` contém o nome `api.sitedocliente.com` (isto é um exemplo), mas note que isto pode ser facilmente burlado.

> Eu não testei o `ProxyPass` nestas condições (tanto local quanto em diferentes servidores), se algo falhar me avise que irei editar a resposta.

Comment: Excelente, uma solução muito simples para um problema bem comum, funcionou perfeitamente, lembrando que geralmente a aplicação usa a porta 8080.